# "Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter"... but I _did_ provide it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, delayed-job

I've read similar posts from others having the same problem, and most people resolved it by including:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '#.#.#.#'}
```

in their environment specific config files. I've done this, and I've also restarted my server.

Here's my mystery. When I try to send an email from my app with a link in it, I get the error in my posting title (as have many others). However, this only is an issue on my staging environment (and Engine Yard instance). My development environment (my local machine) works fine.

In both cases, I have configured action mailer to have a default_url_option as above. For my development environment my :host is local:3000, and for my staging environment (Engine Yard), my :host is an IP address.

I wanted to make sure my staging environment actually loaded the preferences into ActionMailer, so I ran this on the rails console on staging:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
```

which yielded:

```
{:host=>"[the staging ip address from the config file]"}
```

so I know it's in there! But I still am getting "Please provide the :host parameter".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I learned: restarting the *server* isn't the same as restarting the *Delayed Job process*, and thus, any new config settings aren't made available to the Delayed Jobs process unless it is restarted.

After I manually restarted the Delayed Jobs process on my staging server using:

```
bin/delayed_job restart
```

the messages started trickling in.

Quick tip: to force a retry of failed messages in your queue, one at a time, run:

```
Delayed::Job.last.update_attributes(:attempts=>0, :run_at=>Time.now, :failed_at => nil, :locked_by=>nil, :locked_at=>nil)
```